# Batteries AA - industrial R6 vs normal LR6

Tags: electrical-engineering, battery

I have the following issue:

One year ago or so I bought a toy for my kid. Worked fine, then the battery got low (still working though but under performing). I checked the battery type, see is an AA (3 of them). Went to the store and bought some.

Replaced the batteries and the toy won't start at all. Put the old back, toy worked so I checked what went wrong.

Noticed the toy had Industrial Panasonic R6 batteries and I bought Normal Duracell LR6. So I have to questions:

1. Are industrial batteries safe for children (I think yes their main purpose being stability afaik but I must ask :) - kind of like my kid)?
2. Considering the fact that both type of batteries are AA, both have same nominal voltage (1.5) and according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AA_battery the LR6 has actually higher capacity... why is the toy not starting?

Comment: You did put the new ones in in the correct rotation? Or, is one if the new ones faulty??

Comment: The new ones seem (checked them on another toy - not exactly the right way to check but don't have tools here :) ), I put them correctly (that was the first thing I checked).

Comment: **The new batteries seem ok (I forgot one word in the comment above).

Comment: The batteries have different chemistry. The Panasonic R6 is Zinc Choride battery, while the Duracell LR6 is Alkaline. Alkaline batteries have the advantages of higher capacity, longer shelf life, and less chance of leakage, but they have less ability to deliver a high peak current - e.g. for starting a motor in your toy. Presumably, the "Industrial grade R6" has an even higher peak current rating than the "consumer grade R6" would have. For this application, some "cheapest in the store" zinc carbon batteries might be the best option.

Comment: just seen a typo in mine :) , are the new ones out of date?

Comment: Solar Mike no... all are new and fine. alephzero answer makes seems valid but can't find any info on why Zn-C batteries can deliver more current. @alephzero can you explain why pls? – zozo 7 mins ago

Comment: Typo in my previous comment - the R6 is Zinc Carbon not Zinc Chloride. Technical information on Zinc Carbon/Choride batteries seems hard to find on the web - for *most* non-applications Alkaline is better, cheaper (factoring in the longer life), and more readily available in non-specialist retail stores. But Zinc Carbon batteries are often supplied in "batteries included" products, because they are cheaper. The usual "goto" battery site http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/examining_loading_characteristics_on_primary_and_secondary_batteries doesn't say anything useful about them.

Comment: get yourself a volt meter. No point in guessing about these things.

Comment: I disagree with alephzero.  Alkaline generally deliver higher current than zinc-carbon.  ALso battery university does discuss them - and says just that: "Alkaline delivers more energy at higher load currents than zinc-carbon" - http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/choices_of_primary_batteries

Comment: Consumer grade batteries typically has higher protection. When replacing batteries it is generally recommended that the replacement batteries are of same brand, model and same batch. Example it is not recommended to mix new and old batteries. This is because the old battery has higher internal resistance than the new battery. Therefore the new battery will try to source large amount of current. But the old battery might not allow such to happen. As a result pressure build on the old battery, and worse case the new battery might explode. Consumer grade batteries have

Comment: safety to prevent explosion. They have a safety vent that will allow excess pressure the release. There are design compromisers between industrial grade and consumer grade batteries. The design compromise could be Panasonic R6 has higher start up current over the Duracell LR6 battery. Attach are the links to [Panasonic Zinc carbon R6 Battery](https://mediap.industry.panasonic.eu/assets/imported/industrial.panasonic.com/cdbs/www-data/pdf2/AAC4000/AAC4000C25.pdf) and  [Duracell Alkaline-Manganese Dioxide Battery LR6 battery](https://www.duracell.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/QU1500_US_UL1.pdf)

Comment: Another set of good source [Duracell - Alkaline-Technical-Bulletin](https://d2ei442zrkqy2u.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/Alkaline-Technical-Bulletin.pdf), [Alkaline batteries versus zinc batteries](https://www.panasonic-batteries.com/en/news/alkaline-batteries-versus-zinc-batteries), [Eveready Carbon Zinc Battery](https://data.energizer.com/PDFs/carbonzinc_appman.pdf), [Alkaline Manganese Dioxide](https://data.energizer.com/pdfs/alkaline_appman.pdf)

Comment: @zozo, What is the type of toy? Does the toy have motors?

Comment: @user8055 to be fair I don't remember. been 4 years :)).